# From MVC Razor / jQuery to AngularJS - Possible pitfalls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, validation, razor

What kind of potential pitfalls might AngularJS have migrating from a MVC Razor view engine with jQuery project?

Some issues that I haven't bumped into yet, while just beginning to read the simple tutorials, are critical topics such as validation and localization (I can't think of a good list of potential pitfalls offhand). I'd like some input from MVC / Razor devs who have made the switch with an internationalized web application *(localizable and validatable in different cultures etc. which can be tricky even in MVC although MVC does have mechanisms to help)*.

Have you successfully made the switch, or found reasons to avoid making the switch?

What are the pitfalls of moving from server side MVC to client side MVC, specifically in relation to localization and validation? Do you have to write validation twice (server/client side)?

Comment: no idea what you are asking... should make your questions more specific. You are comparing apples to oranges

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question.  What ate the pitfalls of moving from server side MVC to client side MVC, specifically in relation to localization and validation.  I'm personally rather interested in any answers related to validation.  Javascript validation injected into the page based on data annotations on your server side model is huge.  Do you lose that moving everything to the client?  Are you forced to write validation code twice, both client side and server side?  I'm in the process of learning angular my self and I haven't done anything with validation yet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify it a bit, that was a good description. I'm not sure what's wrong with the question, I think somebody with with MVC/Razor experience understands ViewModel validation and resources etc. and would know what they had to to to make it work with AngularJS taking over the client side, or any setbacks they ran into. Also, I'm not trying to broadly "compare" them, just wondering if they are able to successfully migrate and solve the issues mentioned (and any others) which aren't exactly trivial without solid support.